# How does this site decrypt SHA256 hashes?

Tags: hash, sha, decryption, sha256

I thought sha256 is impossible to crack (so far).
But I saw a website, that could decrypt my hash.
So is this because they store known hastes in a database or
do they really decrypt hashes?
Here's an image:
[image: Website decrypts SHA256 and SHA1 Hash?]

Comment: You should read about rainbow tables.

Comment: I don't think sites like these use rainbow tables, i.e. they don't store hash chains and don't compute hashes until they hit a match. I think they just have lookup tables with all hashes and corresponding plain texts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct, the hash functions `SHA256`, `SHA384` and `SHA512` are (currently) unbroken, so it is not possible to easily reverse them. `MD5` and `SHA1` are considered broken because researchers have found pairs of strings that produce the same hash value, but even these require weeks or months of computation.

*(note: I don't like that the site uses "decrypt" because that's a word you use for encryption; you can't "decrypt" a hash)*

What they are probably doing is a [dictionary attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_attack) in which they have pre-computed the hashes for all common dictionary words. This would give them a lookup table which would take in a hash and return the word that produces it.

Just to give an idea of scale, there are 171,476 English words and a `SHA256` hash takes 32 bytes, so storing the `SHA256` hashes of all English words would only take about 5 mb.

Comment: OK, thank you very much for answering and editing ;). Yes, this is actually very confusing, that they are talking about decrypting!

Comment: There are no tricks to reverse MD5 and SHA1. They are considered broken because it is possible to construct two messages with the same hash.

Comment: OK, thanks! So the only secure and famous hashing algorithm is SHA256?

Comment: @Sjoerd Thanks for keeping me honest, I'm writing too fast!

Comment: @K.NaN Be careful with the word "only". But yes, SHA2 (which includes SHA256, SHA384, and SHA512) is good. So is SHA3, and BLAKE. There are more, but they are less famous. It also depends what you're doing; if you're checksumming a file, then SHA1 or MD5 are fine. If it is protecting your bank account, then you should use SHA2 or SHA3.

Comment: I was totally triggered by the words "Decrypt" and "Hash", but you already explained it :p

Answer (score 5):

Your hash wasn't cracked, it was pre-computed and put into a [rainbow table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table).

Hashing is a one-way cryptographic function designed to be compared to and not decrypted like a value that has been encrypted.

So what this website has done is taken a bunch of strings, hashed them using various algorithms and stored the value of the hash. That way when you enter your hash, it compares that hash to values it's already stored to seemingly "reverse" the hash. This is why using a [salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) is so important while hashing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast answer. I'm relieved to hear that! But when hashing is one-way cryptographic, how is it possible to decrypt MD5?

Comment: It wasn't decrypted. But it was cracked.

Comment: My take on this is that it's not really worthwhile generating a rainbow table for one target. The whole point of the rainbow tables was to use them more than once which has been negated by salting and peppering.

Comment: @user633551 I'm sure there's no shortage of applications storing hashes with unsalted hashing algorithms

Comment: @DKNUCKLES well, that's a big mistake by those who use such applications. Also, I bet this won't be encountered when attempting to extract the important credentials. However, I can see how this is related because people are still using same passwords for different logins.